# Is there a word describing the activity of killing somebody with a knife?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I am looking especially for a verb.

Comment: *stab (to death)* or *knife (to death)*.

Comment: As long as you're not especially looking for a knife...

Comment: Why exactly was this question closed as off topic again?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**stabbing**

or **fatal stabbing**

From [oxford](http://An%20act%20or%20instance%20of%20wounding%20or%20killing%20someone%20with%20a%20knife:)

> An act or instance of wounding or killing someone with a knife:

Comment: Thank You! That was the word I was looking for. I totally forgot it.

Comment: stab stab stab stab

Answer (score 5):

*[Gore](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gore)*:

> transitive verb   :
>   to pierce or wound with something pointed (as a horn or knife)
>
> Origin of GORE
>
> Middle English, probably from gore spear, sword, from Old English gār
>   spear First Known Use: 15th century
>
> *merriam-webster.com*

Answer (score 2):

***knifing him to death/demise***

perhaps ... ?

> Yvonne Strahovski 65 Success Facts - Everything you need ... Christine
>   Gallegos - 2014
>
> However, Logan comes foremost and challenges the Sheikh, disclosing
>   him that the images are bogus and then **knifing him to demise**.

Comment: "knifing him to death" sounds good and is in my opinion the most accurate answer to the OP's question. To me, "knifing him to demise" sounds very odd, though, if not outright ungrammatical: I would greatly prefer "knifing him to his demise", but as I said I think "to death" is better and more straightforward anyway.